# Cannot install flask-mysqldb

Tags: python, sql, visual-studio, flask, pip

I've been trying to install `flask-mysqldb` using `pip install flask-mysqldb`, but every time I try it gives me an error that says :

> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

I've looked around a lot and no answer works for me. I searched the file in https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ but its not there.

I am on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course you can not find whl for `flask-mysqldb`, but you can find `mysqlclient`.

Download suitable version for you platform from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient

Then, e.g. `pip install mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl`, depends what you download.

Finally, `pip install flask-mysqldb` again, this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

the same issue/problem I've also received,
That is `flask_mysqldb` 'no module'
first of all flask_mysqldb isn't installed through `pip`,
You have to install a suitable version for `mysqlclient`
for me it worked
I'm using `window 10` having `python3.8` installed....... to rectfiy the error use the follwing procedure:
click on the link
 https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient and select `mysqlclient‑1.4.6‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl` (`python3.8` a suitable version for me) download it 
then search for the directory where downloaded ..... and then through command prompt type

```
pip install mysqlclient‑1.4.6‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl
```

and then

```
pip install flask_mysqldb
```

and done

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'Search for the directory where downloaded'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

I was using python 3.8 and it's not supported by this package.
https://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ : *Flask-MySQLdb is compatible with and tested on Python 2.7, 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7*

I recreated a virtual environment with python 3.7 and it all worked.

installing above must be made

Answer (score 0):

*For Windows*

install  `pip install wheel`

after go to on your browser ' [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python) '

find the appropriate package for the python version and download.

and copy that file to C:\Users<your-computer-name> .

go to cmd again and write here `pip install flask-mysqldb`

Comment: "find the appropriate package for the python version and download", could you please clarify what library?