# How to install Flask-mysqldb for Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, ubuntu-18.04, flask-mysql

I am new to Python and Python-Flask and have ran into an error. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and Python 2.7.15+ to build a python-flask web application.

When installing flask-mysqldb I run into an error.

```
$ pip install flask-mysqldb
```

The full output:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Processing ./.cache/pip/wheels/fd/c9/ef/e0e99dfcf898bc040267e36c4a414ff0b22239968a25161012/Flask_MySQLdb-0.2.0-cp27-none-any.whl
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/9b/5db9a03e2088a87c26e3e4d4c7f7e8f4c2dbae610f9521cdfac15755a795/mysqlclient-1.4.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-mysqldb) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (2.10.3)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask>=0.10->flask-mysqldb) (1.1.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-Gno8ny/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-Gno8ny/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-OrgtfM --python-tag cp27
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-Gno8ny/mysqlclient/
  Complete output (40 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-PPrPZj/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,5,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
  MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_field_to_python’:
  MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1142:33: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PyInt_FromString’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
           return PyInt_FromString(rowitem, NULL, 10);
                                   ^~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:89:0,
                   from MySQLdb/_mysql.c:38:
  /usr/include/python2.7/intobject.h:37:24: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
   PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyInt_FromString(char*, char**, int);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-PPrPZj/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-PPrPZj/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -latomic -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient, flask-mysqldb
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-Gno8ny/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-Gno8ny/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-uh9IqO/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-Gno8ny/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (40 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-PPrPZj/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,5,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_field_to_python’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1142:33: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PyInt_FromString’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
             return PyInt_FromString(rowitem, NULL, 10);
                                     ^~~~~~~
    In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:89:0,
                     from MySQLdb/_mysql.c:38:
    /usr/include/python2.7/intobject.h:37:24: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
     PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyInt_FromString(char*, char**, int);
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-PPrPZj/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-PPrPZj/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -latomic -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-Gno8ny/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-Gno8ny/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-uh9IqO/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.`
```

I have read several other questions and solutions (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228348/12403455) which suggested using:

`mysqlclient‑1.4.5‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl`

So I installed this by using:

```
 $ pip install mysqlclient-1.4.5-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

And ran into an error:

```
Requirement 'mysqlclient‑1.4.5‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
mysqlclient‑1.4.5‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl is not a valid wheel filename.
```

I am unsure how to resolve this issue or how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not use `mysqlclient‑1.4.5‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl` as you found in other answer, because that is a wheel for Windows and you are on Linux.

The project [`mysqlclient`](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/#files), which is a dependency of `flask-mysqldb`, does not distribute wheels for Linux, so you have to build from source code directly (`mysqlclient-1.4.5.tar.gz`).

Your install likely fails due to missing build dependencies.

As the [project landing page has mentioned](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python#prerequisites), install the build dependencies first:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev libssl-dev
```

Then try again to `pip install --user flask-mysqldb`.

Comment: I have tried the suggested answer and still get the "Failed building wheel for mysqlclient".

Comment: Show the full output, please.  Edit it into your question.

Comment: Have now included full output.

Comment: @Rose  From the output, it looks like you're also missing some crypto deps.  Could you try `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` and then try again `pip install flask-mysqldb`.

Comment: It has now produced a new error: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysqlclient-1.4.5.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: That means the package is now correctly building, but you're trying to install somewhere that you don't have permissions to write (system site packages). The resolution suggested in the message is correct. If you are regular user, then you will want to use `pip install --user flask-mysqldb`.

Comment: it's really help for me. I am using ubuntu 20.04 and python 3.8. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I followed instructions from this answer
[mysql_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface)

Just in case I ran

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

later

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

and finally

```
pip3 install flask-mysqldb
```

and it worked, with Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10: `pip install flask-mysqldb`

This worked for me.

Comment: please surround the command in code tags, aka put backticks (`) before and after it. It makes it easier for people to see. Thanks!