# I run into the following error when trying to install MySQL connector for Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, mysql-python

I try to run `pip3 install flask_mysqldb` command but it throws me the following error
[this the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE69R.png). Any suggestions on how to resolve the error?

Thanks.

I want to install a python library to connect mysqldb with my flask web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are dependencies needed to install flask_mysqldb

On https://pypi.org/project/Flask-MySQLdb/ say:

"Quickstart

First, you may need to install some dependencies for mysqlclient if you don't already have them, see [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient#install)."

Also, there are similar questions on StackOverflow, like:

[How to install Flask-mysqldb for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957474/how-to-install-flask-mysqldb-for-python)

Try to not link to images with error messages, copy the error here

Comment: Exactly what I needed to see. Thanks for the reply